# Tensorflow return similar images

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, google-image-search

I want to use Google's Tensorflow to return similar images to an input image.

I have installed Tensorflow from http://www.tensorflow.org (using PIP installation - pip and python 2.7) on Ubuntu14.04 on a virtual machine CPU.

I have downloaded the trained model Inception-V3 (inception-2015-12-05.tgz) from http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz that is trained on ImageNet Large Visual Recognition Challenge using the data from 2012, but I think it has both the Neural network and the classifier inside it (as the task there was to predict the category). I have also downloaded the file classify_image.py that classifies an image in 1 of the 1000 classes in the model.

So I have a random image image.jpg that I an running to test the model. when I run the command:

```
python /home/amit/classify_image.py --image_file=/home/amit/image.jpg
```

I get the below output: (Classification is done using softmax)

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 3
trench coat (score = 0.62218)
overskirt (score = 0.18911)
cloak (score = 0.07508)
velvet (score = 0.02383)
hoopskirt, crinoline (score = 0.01286)
```

Now, the task at hand is to find images that are similar to the input image (image.jpg) out of a database of 60,000 images (jpg format, and kept in a folder at /home/amit/images). I believe this can be done by removing the final classification layer from the inception-v3 model, and using the feature set of the input image to find cosine distance from the feature set all the 60,000 images, and we can return the images having less distance (cos 0 = 1)

Please suggest me the way forward for this problem and how do I do this using Python API.

Comment: I have a few solutions in mind, but I would like to understand the problem more. I assume that you are trying to find all "trench coats" in the 60,000 images. If that's the case, you can simply run all 60,000 images through Inception, extract the images where "trench coat" appears as top 5 (add a threshold value if you would like), and you're done. Does this answer it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the thing is the image file image.jpg above is actually a saree, and I do not want to be limited to only the 1000 classes in the model. Also, if I find a way to add new classes, it will be a very broad classifier and the labeling of images will be a tedious task. So, I was thinking of removing the classification layer from the trained model, and then using the feature vector to calculate nearest images.

Comment: Right. So the problem statement is: "Given 60,000 images, how can I cluster all the sarees together using a modified version of Inception?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found an answer to my question:

In the file classify_image.py that classifies the image using the pre trained model (NN + classifier), I made the below mentioned changes (statements with #ADDED written next to them):

```
def run_inference_on_image(image):
  """Runs inference on an image.
  Args:
    image: Image file name.
  Returns:
    Nothing
  """
  if not gfile.Exists(image):
    tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
  image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()

  # Creates graph from saved GraphDef.
  create_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:
 # Some useful tensors:
 # 'softmax:0': A tensor containing the normalized prediction across
 #   1000 labels.
 # 'pool_3:0': A tensor containing the next-to-last layer containing 2048
 #   float description of the image.
 # 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': A tensor containing a string providing JPEG
 #   encoding of the image.
 # Runs the softmax tensor by feeding the image_data as input to the graph.
 softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
 feature_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0') #ADDED
 predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                        {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
 predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)
 feature_set = sess.run(feature_tensor,
                        {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data}) #ADDED
 feature_set = np.squeeze(feature_set) #ADDED
 print(feature_set) #ADDED
 # Creates node ID --> English string lookup.
 node_lookup = NodeLookup()

 top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
 for node_id in top_k:
   human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
   score = predictions[node_id]
   print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

I ran the pool_3:0 tensor by feeding in the image_data to it. Please let me know if I am doing a mistake. If this is correct, I believe we can use this tensor for further calculations.

Comment: I fetched the pool3 feature set for all of my 50000 images and then I calculated cosine distance with the input image's feature set and rest of the images.. it is showing relevant results, but the color is not that relevant.

Comment: Hey @AmitMadan, I was wondering how did you manage the `feature set` data for all the `50K images`? Did you use `lucene`? Or did you do something else?

Comment: I simply put all images in a folder, and then used a loop to pick each image one by one and passed it as an input. Some modifications in the classify_image.py file. I generated feature set and kept on appending it in a npy file.

Comment: Can you estimate time for calculate single image against the whole set of 50K features?

Comment: So it took me around 10 to 12 hrs for 33k images on my laptop.. i5 8 gb ram. It depends on the image size n the processor.

Comment: Oops you asked the time to match the single input image against 50k feature sets already geberated.. ya so it took me roughly 2 to 3 seconds to find nearest images from the pool of 33k images.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow now has a nice tutorial on how to get the activations before the final layer and retrain a new classification layer with different categories:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/

The example code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

In your case, yes, you can get the activations from pool_3 the layer below the softmax layer (or the so-called bottlenecks) and send them to other operations as input:

[image: retrain imagenet]

Finally, about finding similar images, I don't think imagenet's bottleneck activations are very pertinent representation for image search. You could consider to use an autoencoder network with direct image inputs.

[image: autoencoder]
<sub>(source: [deeplearning4j.org](https://deeplearning4j.org/img/deep_autoencoder.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds similar to this [visual search project](https://github.com/AKSHAYUBHAT/VisualSearchServer)